# Ajax/Jquery calling a webmethod/service every 'interval' seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a ASP.Net web app with jquery implemented on the client side. The client side jquery script makes an asynchronous call to a web method in the server side code. The call returns the status open record(active/inactive) which jquery uses to update the user. The goal is to have jquery repeatedly call the server,  once open record is inactive, then we need to display message to user so that you're no longer associated to this record..I set up the TimeInterval in one off the **HiddenFieldValues** and passing to the Jquery/ajax Function.

This function is written In a separate JavaScript file and it has been referred in my ASPX page Script Manager. I have to pass 'interval' from the server side, which is configured in the .config file.

```
function myWebServiceFunction(val1, val2, val3, interval) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Application/WebServices/MyService.asmx/CheckFunction",
                    data: "{'val1':'" + val1 + "','val2':'" + val2 + "','val3':'" + val3 + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        debugger;
                        var obj = function callbackfunction() {
                            myWebServiceFunction(HealthCarrierShortName, authID, networkID, interval)
                        }
                        if (!msg.d) {


                            window.setTimeout(obj, interval);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Still need to implement how to display to user if the record is not long associated to that user. help me in this too
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('AJAX failure');
                    }
                });
            }
```

In my Server Side, I Used **RegisterStartUpScript** at the end of Page_load method and calling that JQuery Function

```
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Page.GetType(), "AuthLockPolling", " myWebServiceFunction('" + val1HiddenField.Value + "','" + val2HiddenField.Value + "','" + val3HiddenField.value+ "','" + val4HiddenField.value+  ");", True)
```

But it is not working properly(Don't know exactly the reasons). My Jquery function is not being called at all. I testing by placing debugger into my script and it is not been hit.

Still need to implement how to display message to user if the that record is not long associated to that user like in a alert window/pop-up window.  Please help me in this part too.

Please Advise me what went Wrong and How to solve this. Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 1):

How to solve this:

`RegisterStartupScript` can be confusing (ask me how I know!). Are you using this on a page that uses partial-page updates (i.e., has `UpdatePanel` controls)? If not, you should use the method in the `ClientScriptManager` (instead of `ScriptManager`) class.

If it is used on a page with partial-page updates for a control that's *inside* an UpdatePanel, the first parameter should be a control within the `UpdatePanel`, rather than the `Page`.

And a debugging tip: Test by passing in JavaScript code that's drop-dead simple, like `alert('Hello, World!');`. This can help you tell if the problem is in the RegisterStartupScript call or in your myWebServiceFunction function.

Finally, here's the Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408(v=vs.110).aspx. Because there are methods of the same name in different classes, read the documentation verwy, verwy, carefulwee.